# Running laravel application with docker [file not found] window

Tags: php, laravel, docker, window

I am new to Docker and I am trying to dockerize a laravel project.
I successfully run that project using Docker.And my docker application shown in docker ps.
But when I run it in browser with ip address,It says 'file not found' and doesn't show the application.
I can't find solution anywhere.so

I am in window 10 home and I use docker for window.

[image: docker-compose.yml]

[image: app.docker]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoRVX.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The server seems to be up and running. What happens when you access `192.168.99.100:8080/readme.md`? Does it show the readme file? (because you mapped the current directory of project to www, which IMHO should be the public directory)

Comment: it didn't show readme file and same error occured: File not found

Comment: Can you show the error log of Nginx?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uSdQbX6 docker compose log